# How can I tell Django not to cache when there is a an "Authorization" Header

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using django with a DRF and JWT token to authenticate users. I am using caching to cache api response, but I do not want to do that for the logged in users.

What I have in mind is something like using the from `vary_on_headers` which checks the request header `Authorization` and then not cache the response, but I cannot programmatically find a way to do this in python/django.

Current way of doing caching is through a mixing

```
class CacheMixin(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```